# Passing dates to a procedure in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I get this error when I execute command (`rsMas.Open cmd.Execute`):

`Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.`

Here are my params:

```
Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@startDate", adDate, adParamInput, 0, startDate)
cmd.Parameters.Append (prm)

Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@endDate", adDate, adParamInput, 0, endDate)
cmd.Parameters.Append (prm)
```

`StartDate` and `endDate` are Date type and assigned from two cells on a sheet. Values are `10/1/2011`, `10/31/2011`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What database are you using?  How are your date cells formatted?

Comment: US format versus european format dates?

Comment: SQL server 2005, cells are in mm/dd/yyyy. I check in vba that the data is indeed a date using IsDate Function. And I then dim startDate and assign the value of the cell.

Comment: See here for an example of passing a date parameter: http://www.pbdr.com/vbtips/db/StoredProc.htm   It uses a string representation of the date parameter value.

Comment: What is the first line of the sub or function into which you are passing (rsMas.Open cmd.Execute)?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

`cmd.Parameters.Append (prm)`

with:

`cmd.Parameters.Append prm`

or if you really must have parentheses:

`Call cmd.Parameters.Append(prm)`

Using unnecessary parentheses in VBA is the source of many problems

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Instead of using rsMas.Open cmd.Execute I used Set rsMas = cmd.Execute

Thanks for your help